# HOUR_OF_DAY sets the same hour for value 0 and 1

Tags: java, timezone

I have a tricky (at least for me) question with java time zones. I will start with an example that works as expected:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(tz);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
System.out.println("0: " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
System.out.println("1: " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
System.out.println("2: " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

output:

```
0 4/28/17 12:27 AM
1: 4/28/17 1:27 AM
2: 4/28/17 2:27 AM
```

And now a little of magic:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Cairo");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(tz);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
System.out.println("0: " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
System.out.println("1: " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
System.out.println("2: " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

output:

```
0: 4/28/17 1:31 AM
1: 4/28/17 1:31 AM
2: 4/28/17 2:31 AM
```

Could someone explain me why HOUR_OF_DAY for values 0 and 1 set hour on the same value for specific TimeZone's?

Comment: Might be related to Daylight Saving Time (DST). I don't know how DST are handled in Java for such TimeZones which seem to have very irregular DST policies.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It works fine for me. I wonder whether you have an old version of time zone data, where maybe April 28th 2017 was a "skip forward" day...

Comment: I'm using jdk1.8.0_25. Not very fresh but not too old also

Comment: Old enough to be at least 7 time zone data versions out of date :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your machine has an old version of time zone data, in which Egypt would have put the clocks forward at midnight local time at the start of April 28th 2017. Therefore 12:31am wouldn't have existed, and Java is skipping forward by an hour instead<sup>1</sup>.

On July 5th 2016, IANA time zone data 2016f was released with the change to the Africa/Cairo time zone to not observe DST from that point onwards. (This was a very late announcement, as the next change *would* have been July 8th 2016.)

You can see all the transitions for every IANA time zone, across different versions of the IANA data, at http://nodatime.github.io/tzvalidate/. (Disclaimer: I build that page. I started the tzvalidate project to validate that different date/time libraries understand the time zone data in the same way.)

---

<sup>1</sup> I would argue that the API should force you to state what you want to happen in that case, but I won't go into *everything* that's wrong with `java.util.Calendar` here...

Answer (score 3):

A few years ago, that timezone was planned to have a DST transition the night of the 28th of April 2017: at 00:00am, clocks would have been moved forward by one hour. So a time between midnight and 1am would have been invalid due to the transition.

However that transition did not occur in practice because it was cancelled (Egypt seem to have cancelled and reinstated DST a few times over the past few years).

In conclusion, you are probably using an older version of Java which has an outdated timezone database.

Comment: That would make sense *if* Cairo actually had that transition. It doesn't according to current data. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/egypt/cairo I'll see whether I can find an old version where that actually happened.

Comment: @JonSkeet I checked there: http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo?tz=Africa/Cairo - not sure which is right.

Comment: @JonSkeet I found that Cairo had such DST on the 30 of April in 2010. I would be interested to know what is the reference for DSTs in Java's `Date` class.

Comment: Looks like timezoneconverter.com has out-of-date data - but probably the same data that the OP has. Ah, the joys of time zone data changing.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: I believe most Java implementations use the IANA data: https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Answer (score 0):

You were right. Problem was with time transition at 28th. Today everything works fine :)